# What is a pseudodisk?

Tags: computational-geometry

I'm reading a [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1208.2785.pdf) on computational geometry and the term pseudodisk popped up. A simple googling doesn't provide me with any mathematical definitions.

Could anyone please explain to me the definition of a pseudodisk?

Edit: For more context: "It has been proved that for geometric objects with finite VC dimension d, there exist $\epsilon$-nets of size $O(\frac{d}{\epsilon}\log\frac{1}{\epsilon})$. $\epsilon$-nets of size $O(\frac{1}{\epsilon})$ exist for halfspaces in $\mathbb{R^2}$ and $\mathbb{R^3}$ and pseudo-disks in $\mathbb{R^2}$." Let me know if this is not enough.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please give some of the context you found that word in.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a pseudodisk?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2167403/what-is-a-pseudodisk)

Answer (score 1):

I could find this reference and short explanation, but nothing detailed: "A set of objects is a collection of pseudo-disks, if the boundary of every pair of them intersects at most twice." [Chan and Sariel](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1103.1431.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Consider two planar objects $o_1$ and $o_2$, each bounded by a simple closed
curve. Intuitively, the pair $o_1,o_2$ is called a pair of pseudo-disks if their boundaries $\partial o_1$ and $\partial o_2$ intersect in at most two points.